# How to make the largest square possible from smaller squares

Tags: problem-solving

Using two - $ 4 \times 4$ squares, three - $3 \times 3 $ squares, four - $2 \times 2$ squares and four - $1  \times 1$ squares  draw a diagram to show how you can make a square using some or all of these squares together without gaps or overlaps to make a square that is as large as possible.
Explain why you cannot make a square larger than this square.

*problem-solving*

Comment: Do you know the answer already?

Comment: What have you tried?  The total area of the squares gives an upper limit.  Have you found that?  Can you achieve that?

Comment: No- Hence the question. I am  in Year 8 at school and i need help. 79 squares is the total area once you add all of the segments together. SO does that mean an 8 x 8 square is the maximum area, since 9 x9 would be too big

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was suggesting.  That does not guarantee that you can make $8 \times 8$, but means you don't need to look at $9 \times 9$  Also note that if you don't use one $4 \times 4$ you only have $63$ available, so if you are going to make $8 \times 8$ you need to use both of the $4 \times 4$s.

Answer (score 0):

I can get $6 \times 6$ as shown in the first figure below.  I can get close to $8 \times 8$ but would need six $1 \times 1$ squares to finish the second figure, not four.  I haven't proven that $7 \times 7$ and $8 \times 8$ are impossible.  The problem is that the $4 \times 4$ and $3 \times 3$ squares don't provide enough flexibility.  To really prove that you would have to go through all the possible locations for the big squares and show they don't work.
[image]
[image]